# Why is this code which is supposed to request an operation then do the necessary calculations not working

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop, calculator

```
include using namespace std;

int main() {
  float n1, n2, sum, diff, pro, quot;
  char f;

  cout << "PLease enter your function(A,S,D,M or X to end the program" << endl;
  cin >> f;

  while (f != 'A', 'S', 'D', 'M', 'X') {
    cout << "Invalid Operation" << endl;
    cout << "PLease enter your function(A,S,D,M or X to end the program"
         << endl;
    cin >> f;
  }

  if (f == 'X') return 0;
  if (f == 'A', 'S', 'D', 'M') {
    cout << "Please enter two numbers";
    cin >> n1 >> n2;

    if (f == 'A') {
      sum = n1 + n2;
      cout << sum;
    }

    else if (f == 'S') {
      if (n1 > n2) {
        diff = n1 - n2;
        cout << diff;
      } else {
        diff = n2 - n1;
        cout << diff;
      }
    } else if (f == 'D') {
      if (n1 > n2) {
        quot = n1 / n2;
        cout << quot;
      } else {
        quot = n2 / n1;
        cout << quot;
      }
    } else if (f == 'M') {
      pro = n1 * n2;
      cout << pro;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Its not accepting A,S,M,D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` statement is the problem. It's using the comma expression, which is not what you want because it ends up evaluating finally to 'X'. You need to compare `f` to each of your options separately.

One way to accomplish this is to expand the comparison in the `while` statement to something like

```cpp
while (f != 'A' && f != 'S' && f != 'D' && f != 'M' && f != 'X')
{
  ...
}
```

The same is true for your `if` statement a few lines below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the logic is not inside the while loop that is why it cannot go through the necessary if and else, so I edited your code and applied some changes.

Changes:

-->I removed the first **cout** of your code since you only need the one "Input statement" that is inside your while loop.

-->I placed the conditional statements inside your while loop.

-->I added a new else statement to place the word "Invalid Operation"

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float n1,n2,sum,diff,pro,quot; char f;

    while (f!='A','S','D','M','X'){
        cout<<"Please enter your function(A,S,D,M or X to end the program"<<endl;
        cin>>f;

        if(f=='X'){
           return 0; 
        }
        else if (f=='A'){
            cout<<"Add";
            sum=n1+n2; 
            cout<<sum<<endl;
        }
        else if (f=='S'){
            cout<<"Subtract";
            if (n1>n2){
                diff=n1-n2;
                cout<<diff<<endl;
            }
            else{
                diff=n2-n1;
                cout<<diff<<endl;
            }
        }
        else if (f=='M'){
            cout<<"Multiply";
            pro=n1*n2; 
            cout<<pro<<endl;
        }
        else if (f=='D'){
            cout<<"Divide";
            if (n1>n2){
                quot=n1/n2;
                cout<<quot<<endl;
            }
            else{
                quot=n2/n1;
                cout<<quot<<endl;
            }

        }
        else{
            cout<<"Invalid Operation"<<endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The main problem was my while loop and if statement which needed to be in this format (f != 'A' && f != 'S' && f != 'D' && f != 'M' && f != 'X')

Comment: Yes there are a lot of possibilities in order to solve your question.

I created a sample of this code to show that this is also working
https://onlinegdb.com/S1beJNaFS